# Plotting data that matches a condition from another row in Tibco Spotfire

Tags: spotfire, tibco

I am relatively new to Spotfire and i wanted to ask the following question:
I am trying to plot data from a column "Value" when another row matches a condition from 2 other columns (When "String Tag" = F and "String ID" = Z Then plot "Value" when "String Tag" = A, green highlighted rows). So to clarify my problem added a snapshot of the table:

[image: Table image]

Same thing to do with the yellow and red highlighted rows. Can anybody help me with this question? Is this possible in Spotfire?

regards,

Addi

Comment: It isn't clear to me what you're trying to do here. Can you be specific about how the rows will relate to each other and what kind of plot you're trying to make?

Answer (score 0):

I want to plot the scatter plot with "Datetime" on x-axis and "Value" on y-axis. For each highlighted block i want to make separate scatter plots as there are more values structured like this. I have added another column to clarify further. If I plot "Result" column against "Datetime" i get my answer. However, i don't know how can create the "Result" column using calculated column functionality.

[updated example snapshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/P0vnQ.png)